# Convert a hash into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am trying to create a method that will take a hash:

```
{"H"=> 1, "e"=> 1, "l"=> 3, "o"=> 2, "W"=> 1, "r"=> 1, "d"=> 1}
```

as a parameter and return an array of its key-value pairs like such:

```
arr = [["H", 1], ["e", 1], ..., ["d", 1]]
```

I have the following, but it is flawed:

```
def toCountsArray(counts)
  arr = []
  i = 0
  counts.each do |key, value|
    arr[i].push [key, value]
    i += 1
  end
  return arr
end
```

I am not supposed to use the `to_a` method or any kind of helper like that. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Note, when writing Ruby, there's a very strong convention for method names to be `underscore_style`, not `mixedCase`. It's a little thing but it helps your code fit in better, avoiding programming with an accent.

Comment: I am following the coding style that my professor has provided us with, I agree with you though. @tadman

Comment: I'd ask your professor for a style guide link that explains those quirky conventions because I've never seen one advocate that. If they've got some irregular requirements I hope they're codified somewhere.

Comment: @tadman I emailed him and because this is a programing languages class where we learn multiple languages at a basic level he said that he uses camel case to make things easier on him but that I was technically right

Comment: Although I like promoting conventions that can be applied broadly, Ruby is usually particular about case: `ALL_CAPS` is used to declare constants, there's no way around that. In C++ or Java you have considerable latitude there, but to ignore it in the Ruby world is to miss a large part of what makes the language consistent and readable. It's like learning French from a teacher who doesn't pronounce the words correctly. I could teach a whole class on the significance of whitespace, punctuation and case in various programming languages, so I hope that gets touched on in yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically there. The arbitrary restriction on `to_a` is odd, since there's many ways to get effectively the same thing. Still, to fix your original example:

```
array = [ ]
counts.each do |pair|
  array << pair
end
```

That's a messy way of doing `to_a`, but it should work. Your mistake was trying to append to a *specific element* of `array`, not append to the array itself.

A pattern to use when doing this sort of operation is this:

```
counts = Hash.new(0)
```

That creates a Hash with a default value of `0` for each element. This avoids the dance you have to do to assign to an undefined key.

There's a few other things you can do to reduce this and make it more Ruby-like:

```
def count_chars(string)
  string.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, counts|
    case (char)
    when ' '
      # Ignored
    else
      counts[char] += 1
    end
  end
end
```

The `each_with_object` method is handy in that it iterates over an array while passing through an object that each iteration can make use of. Combining the trick of having a Hash with a default value makes this pretty tidy.

If you have a longer list of "to ignore" characters, express that as an array. `string.chars - exclusions` can then delete the unwanted ones. I've used a `case` statement here to make adding special behaviour easier.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash = { "H"=> 1, "e"=> 1, "l"=> 3, "o"=> 2, "W"=> 1, "r"=> 1, "d"=> 1 }

p [*hash]
# => [["H", 1], ["e", 1], ["l", 3], ["o", 2], ["W", 1], ["r", 1], ["d", 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
arr[i].push [key, value]
```

use

```
arr.push [key, value]
```

because `arr[i]` refers to the i-th element

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
hash = { "H"=> 1, "e"=> 1, "l"=> 3, "o"=> 2, "W"=> 1, "r"=> 1, "d"=> 1 }

hash.each_with_object([]) { |kv, a| a << kv }
#=> [["H",1],["e",1],["l",3],["o",2],["W",1],["r",1],["d",1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
def to_counts_array(counts)
  counts.map { |k, v| [k, v] }
end

h = { "H"=> 1, "e"=> 1, "l"=> 3, "o"=> 2, "W"=> 1, "r"=> 1, "d"=> 1 }
to_counts_array(h)
```

Although I like the @steenslag's answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, just map to self:

```
x.map &:itself #=> [["H", 1], ["e", 1], ["l", 3], ["o", 2], ["W", 1], ["r", 1], ["d", 1]]
```